# how to load the dependencies from the pom into classpath of eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, classpath, pom.xml

Am using eclipse helios with m2eclipse plugin. For a maven project checked out from CVS, how do i tell eclipse to automatically fetch all the jars needed for that project from the dependencies mentioned in the pom.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

m2eclipse should do this for you (dependencies will be copied to your local repository) and build a valid classpath. 
I you have any doubts that the resolved dependencies are outdated try

```
<select project> -> Context Menu -> Maven -> Update Dependencies
```

If you want to guarantee that all dependencies (and plugins) are in your local repository you can run the [go-offline](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html) goal from the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/):

```
mvn dependency:go-offline
```

If you want to copy all needed dependencies to one place, use the [copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) goal

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

The Maven Dependency Plugin will copy all dependencies (including transitive) to the `target/dependency` folder in this case.

You can run all these commands also from eclipse using:

```
<select project> -> Context Menu -> Run As -> Maven build... -> <type goals> -> Run
```